# Geolocation api, where is the info.plist file if I create the app with expo?

Tags: ios, react-native, geolocation

I'm struggling to get the geolocation info, latitude and longitude.
I tried these two [react-native-geolocation-service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-geolocation-service), [@react-native-community/geolocation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/geolocation) ,  but immediately after the import I get error:

> Error: @react-native-community/geolocation: NativeModules.RNCGeolocation is null. To fix this issue try these steps:
> • Run `react-native link @react-native-community/geolocation` in the project root.
> • Rebuild and re-run the app.
> • If you are using CocoaPods on iOS, run `pod install` in the `ios` directory and then rebuild and re-run the app. You may also need to re-open Xcode to get the new pods.

In the docs is written that I have to add the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` and `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription` in Info.plist, but there is no info.plist because the app was mede with expo (If I not wrong). So, how can I solve this problem? Also I'm using the ios simulator, not the android studio.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try [this one](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/location/) for expo projects, geolocation that you used was for react native cli